# X axis not displaying on Multi Series Line Chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am implementing a multi series line chart in d3.js following the example on this block: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955. However, the X axis is not displaying. The X axis should display the dates. Here is my code:

```
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]),
    // xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var products = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, price: d[id]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(data.map( function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(products, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.price; }); }),
    d3.max(products, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.price; }); })
  ]);

  z.domain(products.map(function(c) { return c.id; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("Price $");

  var product = g.selectAll(".product")
    .data(products)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "product");

  product.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.id); });

  product.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.price) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
});

function type(d, _, columns) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
  return d;
}
```

Here is the resultant chart from my code:- http://bizvizmap.com/timeseries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some problem in your data, because this plunker has **exactly** your code, with some bogus data I created:

```
date,foo,bar,baz
20160101,11,23,45
20160102,21,22,35
20160103,44,76,54
20160104,31,23,45
20160105,41,63,15
20160106,12,22,25
```

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xZY02zVTEh6o9RwNGJBw?p=preview

The ticks on the x axis are a mess because you're using the full JS date in an ordinal scale. Because of that, it makes more sense using a time scale, as in this other plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/n5u8N9aK8YELtTCHexgR?p=preview

Comment: It worked. As noted the issue was with my data. I was using TSV. Switching to CSV resolved the problem. I did not know that an ordinal scale can cause the mess on the dates. Thanks for taking time to create the plunkers. Very helpful.